# How to split menu in parts with typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I have a Typoscript menu with a lot of items and want to split it into several blocks of 6 items each.

My typoscript looks like this at the moment:

```
lib.mainnav = HMENU
lib.mainnav {

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        wrap = <ul>|</ul>
        expAll = 1

        NO = 1
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        NO.stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        NO.ATagParams = name = "{field:title}"
        NO.allStdWrap.insertData = 1
    }

    [ ... ]

}
```

After every 6th item a `</ul><ul>` should be inserted here. I have already tried a lot of things, but have not yet reached the desired result.

Does anyone have a tip for me?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: optionSplit should solve this (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/OptionSplit.html#objects-optionsplit). Maybe, you have to look for a wrap which supports optionSplit, but in general it should solve your request.

Answer (score 0):

```
NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li> || <li>|</li> || <li>|</li> || <li>|</li> || <li>|</li> || <li>|</li></ul><ul> |*| |*|
```

Keep in mind that you will have an empty `<ul></ul>` if you have a multiple of 6 entries in your menu.